# Representing non-fixed state-spaces in RL algorithms

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

How I can define the state of an environment where I don’t have a fixed representation for states? E.g. the state at one step is a list of size 5 and in another state is a list of size 6. What is the general RL technique for representing states of such environments where we don't have a fixed-size representation of the environment?